# Override function inside an object calling its initial implementation

Tags: javascript, html, function, oop

This code pretends to override the function: `helper.highlight` which was already prepending `###` to the string passed as argument. After been overridden it's supposed that it also appends `###` to the string.

There is one important detail here, and it is that the new implementation (override) of the function needs to make use of the original implementation.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script>
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
  let output = document.querySelector('.message');
  let result = helper.highlight('Hello World');
  output.innerHTML = result;
});
helper = {
  highlight: str => {
    return '### ' + str;
  }
};
// BEGIN OF YOUR APPROACH
prevHighlight = helper.highlight;
helper.highlight = str => {
  str += ' ###';
  str = prevHighlight(str);
  return str;
};
// END OF YOUR APPROACH
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <span class="message"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

The code works properly as you can see here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/2o503978m0

**What I want to know is:** if the function override can be done without using an additional variable like I do with: `prevHighlight`. Looking for a more clear way to do this.

Any idea about that?

If possible, please, fork my `codesandbox.io` above and paste the new link on your answer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This approach decorates the original function:

```
Function.prototype.affixer = function() {
    var originalHighlight = this;
    var temp = function() {
      // this is not very robust and assumes there is always at least one argument
      arguments[0] += " ###";
      return originalHighlight.apply(this, arguments);
    };
    return temp;
};
helper.highlight = helper.highlight.affixer();
```

See forked example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/726xw524z0

Comment: That's syntactic sugar, but the answer to the question is no. Can you add this to your answer?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible. Take a look at this:

```
helper.highlight = str => {
  str += ' ###';
  str = helper.highlight(str);//prevHighlight(str);
  return str;
};
```

As you can see `highlight` will become recursive this way.